# Consistent numbering graphics and Ascii art figures

Tags: counter, figure, asciidoc, asciidoctor

I am writing a document that has a number of figures, some of them are ASCII art and some are regular PNG images.

When I put a caption before the the image it recognizes it as a figure and displays it "Figure X Caption text" under it.  But, when I put the same caption before ASCII art image it recognizes it as a caption,  but doesn't put any "Figure X" in front of it.

Is there a way to number all of them consistently as figures?

Comment: Can you show us the markup that you are using for each case?

Answer (score 1):

An example of the adoc source would be useful. I am not sure if you have your ASCII art image in a block or not. I will assume that you have it in a block.

You can control the caption test by using `:figure-caption:` and `:example-caption:`. You could set the caption text to be the same, but unfortunately this will create a numbering duplication, since they are tracked seperately.

I would recommend adding a block around your image. So for example if you had:

```
.Image Caption
image::312.jpg[alt]

.Text Caption
====
Hello world
====
```

Which would render as: [image: Example 1]

You could use:

```
.Image Caption
====
image::312.jpg[alt]
====

.Text Caption
====
Hello world
====
```

Which would render as: [image: Example 2]

An alternative would be to unset `:figure-caption:` and `:example-caption:`, and add the number via a counter on your caption. For example:

```
:example-caption!:
:figure-caption!:

.Figure {counter:figure-number} Image Caption
image::312.jpg[alt,width=50]

.Figure {counter:figure-number} Text Caption
====
Hello world
====
```